# Coding JS Underscore _.extend from scratch

Tags: javascript, arguments, underscore.js

Extend has proven challenging because I'm trying to manipulate the arguments object.

My current extend function does not account for more than one argument after the initial given object

```
  _.extend = function(object, sources) {
    return _.reduce(sources, function(memo, current) {
      memo[Object.keys(sources)] = current || 0;
      return memo;
    }, object)
  }
```

At first, I tried to make a copy of the arguments object, turn it into an array, and shift() the first argument out. This is terribly inelegant, but has still proven to be ineffective

I realized that apply() or call() should be used in this context somehow. When I tried it, it also didn't work.

```
_.extend = function(object) {
  var copy = [].slice.call(arguments);
  copy.shift();
  doIT.apply(this, copy);
  var doIt = function(copy) {
    return _.reduce(copy, function(memo, current) {
      memo[Object.keys(copy)] = current || 0;
      return memo;
    }, object)
  }
  doIt(copy);
}
```

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

Comment: `function extend(o){return [].slice.call(arguments).reduce(function(a,b){   Object.keys(b).forEach(function(k){a[k]=b[k];});return a;}, o);}`

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `apply` on your function, just call it normally. By doing so, you are passing your shifted array as a list of arguments into your function. Since you are only working with `copy` in your parameter list then only one argument would make it. There's no need for `call` either, as you can easily invoke the function since no `this` context is required. Lastly, since your function is not a function declaration, it won't be available until the expression holding the function has been evaluated (available after `var doIt`).

Now, your `doIt` function is doing something wrong:

```
memo[Object.keys(copy)] = current || 0;
```

`Object.keys(copy)` returns an array with copy `keys`. So you are doing:

```
memo[array] = current || 0;
```

The `array` will be casted to a string, but it's definitely not something you want either. What you need to is iterate each element properties of the `copy` array (each on is on `current`) and copy those properties into your first object (`memo` accumulator). Like this:

```
var extend = function (object) {
    var copy = [].slice.call(arguments);
    copy.shift();
    var doIt = function (copy) {
        return copy.reduce(function (memo, current) {
            Object.keys(current).forEach(function (key) {
                memo[key] = current[key];
            });
            return memo;
        }, object)
    }
    return doIt(copy);
}
```

However, extends still need to handle the appropriated getters and setters. So you'll need to do something like:

```
var extend = function (object) {
    var copy = [].slice.call(arguments);
    copy.shift();
    var doIt = function (copy) {
        return copy.reduce(function (memo, current) {
            Object.keys(current).forEach(function (key) {
                var pDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(current, key);
                Object.defineProperty(memo, key, pDesc);
            });
            return memo;
        }, object)
    }
    return doIt(copy);
}
```

Comment: okay the second version seems like witchcraft to me. Can you explain the pDesc lines?

Comment: The property descriptor holds a a description of the property in the object. Such as getters, setters, the value of the property, if it's enumerable, configurable or writable, etc. [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) returns the descriptor, [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) defines a property for the object with that same descriptor.